# postgres install issues on ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, installation

I am trying to install postgres on ubuntu and get errors related to fetching. Is there an alternative way to install?

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib

Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/postgresql-  9.1/postgresql-client-9.1_9.1.17-0ubuntu0.12.04_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/postgresql-9.1/postgresql-9.1_9.1.17-0ubuntu0.12.04_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On http://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt you can find list of mirrors recommended for you. If you open `/etc/apt/sources.list` as sudoer with your favourite text editor then you can use mirror. For example:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse
```

You can change to

```
deb http://ubuntu.saix.net/ubuntu-archive/ precise main restricted universe multiverse
```

Naturally you will use one of links from your area. Don't forget to save your old `sources.list`. Also replace `precise` with your version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. Sorry it was an offtopic question technically